What is the name of this TV series in which the protagonist has the ability to disappear?
The series is probably American.
One scene I can remember is when the protagonist wakes up in a room then a lot of small creatures - probably spiders - starts to attack him, then he panics, and notices that his body starts to disappear. Later on he manages to control this ability and uses it during his investigations to hide himself or other things.
There was a female character that has the ability to breath underwater.

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. When did you watch it? What time was it likely from? Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions of scenes or characters you can give? Was it live action or animation? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

When was it released?

You're looking for The Invisible Man (2000 TV Series).  (IMDB: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0220238/)
It ran for 2 seasons from 2000 to 2002.
The main character is Darien Fawkes, who is implanted with a "Quicksilver gland", which when activated allows him to become invisible.  It had side effects, including driving him to madness.  He can extend the quicksilver around other things to hide them too.
One of the characters is Allianora:

Through bio-modification she has gained the ability to breathe water and regurgitate it under pressure, making her capable of drowning people with a kiss.

She only appeared in Season One.

Nice.  This was my first thought on reading the question, but I had forgotten about the girl who could breathe water.

I thought I'd hallucinated this show.
